# Firefox startup parameters

Tags: firefox, command-line

You can start Firefox with parameters, but I'm having trouble finding a definite list of them.

What are some good parameters and what do they do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Firefox Knowledgebase](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments) talks about the command line parameters.  Also there is additional information at the [developer website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Command_Line_Options).

Some of the ones I uses most often:

- `-ProfileManager` - starts the Firefox Profile Manager
- `-P "Profile Name"` - starts Firefox using the specified profile.
- `-safe-mode` - starts Firefox in "Safe Mode" useful when extensions go awry.
- `-no-remote` - permits multiple instances of Firefox using separate profiles.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, but it looks like you have posted exactly the same links as my good old self. :)

Answer (score 2):

MozillaZine:

**[Command line arguments](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments)**

Mozilla Developers Center:

**[Command Line Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Command_Line_Options)**

Answer (score 0):

at 2021
All links provided above at MDN ordeveloper.mozilla.org are failing.

[Archived from mozilla](https://www-archive.mozilla.org/docs/command-line-args)

**Other webs working:**

[ghacks](https://www.ghacks.net/2017/10/08/the-most-important-firefox-command-line-options/)

[Mozillazine](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments) is still working

[devdoc.net](http://www.devdoc.net/web/developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options.html)

**From CommandLine** or a batch script you can call

firefox.exe  -h   | more

(Note that in Windows the pipe and more are necessary due an old firefox bug)